# How to specify Inner URI parameter without value

Tags: rest

In the REST API that I'm designing I have resource URI like this:

```
/user/:userId/data/:key
```

It means the user data of the user with the id of `userId` and with the data key of `key`.

It works good unless I need to get the data with some key for all the users.
The 2 possible solutions I have in mind is to specify `userId` parameter with a special string such as *all* `/user/all/data/:key` or make the `userId` as query string. What is the best practice to use in this case?

Comment: I would introduce a second resource `/data/:key` because you don't access the data of a specific user and rather search through all available data for a given single key and ignore the fact, that the data is coming from a user.

Comment: hmm... but it's the user data.

Comment: No, you don't access the data of a given user - you search all data, so which advantage would it be to access the data through a virtual "all" user?

Comment: I search all the data of users. /data/:key doesn't specify that it's the users data.

Answer (score 0):

Using: `/user/all/data/:key/` is definitely not the way to go. It forces API clients to know some implementation details - a dedicated user named *all* is such a detail.

Much better idea is to use `/users/data/?key=<some key>`. This way you explicitly state that collection of `users` has some `data` and you need to filter these `data` with a given `key`.

Comment: GET /user means to get all the users since there is no id. Notice there is no 's' not plural. In the answer you denote /users to be all the users. It's inconsistency.

Comment: @AraYeressian, it should be probably plural, with _s_, since you need to filter every single subresource (_data_) of _all users_.